# Smart/Auto Slippage

Tags: ethers.js, typescript

Is there a typescript library which can automatically calculate your slippage for you or does someone know how to calculate it?

I'm aware that we can manually fill in slippage but what I need is a calculation so that I don't provide too much or too little slippage.